# Create a soapmonitor applet in axis2 with the help of java?

Tags: java, xml, soap, apache-axis, monitor

Can anybody please reply with how can I make my own soapmonitor applet in axis2 web server and tomcat container using java?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried following the Axis2 docs? Seem pretty comprehensive:

- http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/soapmonitor-module.html